# Modifying headers in Next.js and returning a JSON response

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Can I modify a request header and send a response at the same time with `NextResponse`?

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

const handler = async function(
  req: NextRequest,
  res: NextResponse
) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case "POST": {
      ...
    }
    default: {
      res.headers.set("Allow", "POST");
      return NextResponse.json({
        statusText: `Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`
      });
    }
  }
}

export { handler as POST };
```

I realize the switch check for `POST` may be redundant given the export type, but I still am curious if the above is possible, and if by returning a `NextResponse.json()` will bypass the `res.headers.set()` modification